# PERL widget error

Tags: perl, widget, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use the TK module on PERL to make a window that displays a gel eletrophoresis result on entering values. 
[image]

example original electrophoresis result.

So, in effect I would like to have a black screen on which when you enter values will give white bars on the screen. I am not an expert in programming so, I am using references from online changing commands to suit my need. My current code is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl5 -w

use Tk;

my $main = MainWindow->new();
$main->minsize(qw(900 700));
$main->title("Gel Electrophoresis");
$main->configure (-background => 'black');

MainLoop();

my $menu_bar = $main->Frame(-relief => 'groove', -borderwidth => 100, -background => 'purple',)->pack('-side' => 'top', -fill => 'x');

my $file_mb = $menu_bar->Menubutton(-text=> 'File', -background => 'white', -activebackground => 'cyan', -foreground => 'white',)->pack(-side => 'left');
```

This code give me a black background but the menu bar does not seem to be working. I get the error

> MainWindow=HASH(0x918fa20) is not a widget at bigone.pl line 12

I am following every instruction but can't seem to get this sorted. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a different way of showing menu bar, use this page to get you started:

[12.2. Menubars and Pulldown Menus](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/tk/ch12_02.htm)

You can use this site to learn more advance stuff also...

Good luck.